Can't find "Unused lexical variable 'start'" that startup is warning me about
When I start up Emacs I get this warning in a *Compile-Log* buffer.

Warning (bytecomp): Unused lexical variable 'start'

I grepped for "start" in init.el and the two mode files I use and I don't see a variable named "start".
Is there a way to get it to show which file, and which line it is talking about?
I haven’t changed anything real recently with Emacs. Possibly I have been missing this each time. I only have two files that would be included by init.el: a mode file for the Janet language and one for Vala.

Hmm, that's odd, Emacs usually prints warnings in format file:line:column: Warning: text follows. You can see example in the commit message of this recent fix in a mode. What Emacs version do you have? Nonetheless, what happens if you put caret over the warning line, and press Enter? It should open the file and put you to the line with error.

@Hi-Angel Thanks for the reply. If I put the cursor over the line (it becomes a text cursor) and hit enter I get "Buffer is read-only: #<buffer Compile-Log>"

Okay, but what version do you have?

@Hi-Angel GNU Emacs 27.1,  (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars)  of 2024-09-17, modified by Debian

I see, that kind of explains why the compilation log works differently for you. 27.1 was released almost 5 years ago, can you update Emacs? Emacs is an actively developed project and it has lots of improvements in every release. I guess it works for most desktop projects — you do usually want to be running latest release. But on the context of your question, I'd presume if you update to the latest release, the compilation log would have both fliename:line, and also will allow to navigate to the place immediately by pressing Enter.

Emacs 27 also shows file/line numbers when byte-compiling files.  Most likely the code in question is being compiled in a more dynamic context.  E.g. (byte-compile '(let (foo) t)) => "Warning: Unused lexical variable ‘foo’".  I suggest using recursive bisection to narrow down the cause -- eliminate half of the remaining potential code at each step.

Have you checked with emacs -q? Are you sure it's your init file that's causing it and not e.g. the Debian customizations or something else? If it is your init file, then bisecting it as @phils suggests should get you the culprit very quickly.
